# Boilerplate replies for problem posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation

Are there any tools for the creation of boilerplate replies to problem posts like people making comments as answers, or asking OT questions? Seems like it would be useful.

A bit like on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Boilerplate_text), where boilerplate or templates are used to flag articles with various problems etc.

An example would be the "stack exchange is not a forum…" comment that you see a lot.

Answer (score 4):

There are user scripts for this kind of thing.  Personally, I prefer to write custom messages to each user as the activity level is currently low enough and giving some more personalized attention feels friendlier to me, but such things do exist as things that run in the browser itself.  (There are actually quite a lot of other useful user scripts as well.)

Check out [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts).

Comment: Good point. For me the benefit of a template is that it ensures that the reason given for flagging / downvoting will be clear, correct, and less likely to be taken as the personal opinion of the flagger / downvoter.